# imagecreatefrompng() from base64 code?

Tags: php, png, base64, imagecreatefrompng

is there a way to create an image with imagecreatefrompng() with [this](http://minecraft.goldencreate.com/data_uri.php?img_url=http://avatars.goldencreate.com/skin/char&img_type=image/png) base 64 PNG code in PHP?

Comment: Yes, take a look at http://php.net/imagecreatefromstring and http://php.net/base64_decode (edit: actualy there is a sample on the first page)

Comment: Yes, i was on that page earlier and i tried it, but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you strip off the `data:image/png;base64,`?

Comment: Oh, i guess i didn't, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```php
<?php
$data = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABl'
       . 'BMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDr'
       . 'EX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV+wULF4Avk9fLq2r'
       . '8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
$data = base64_decode($data);

$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
if ($im !== false) {
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
}
else {
    echo 'An error occurred.';
}
?>
```